# Change variable values with different iterations

Tags: r, dataframe

Considering that I have 2 different objects. The first is a data frame (`df`), and it looks like this:

```
>df
Pos         MHC    Peptide
  1 HLA-A*02:01 VTGYKVQYTS
  2 HLA-A*02:01 TGYKVQYTSL
  3 HLA-A*02:01 GYKVQYTSLT
  4 HLA-A*02:01 YKVQYTSLTG
  5 HLA-A*02:01 KVQYTSLTGL
  1 HLA-A*02:01 SHDLGIILQK
  2 HLA-A*02:01 HDLGIILQKI
  3 HLA-A*02:01 DLGIILQKIR
  4 HLA-A*02:01 LGIILQKIRD
  5 HLA-A*02:01 GIILQKIRDM
  6 HLA-A*02:01 IILQKIRDMP
  7 HLA-A*02:01 ILQKIRDMPY
  8 HLA-A*02:01 LQKIRDMPYM
  1 HLA-A*02:01 MGLEALMPLA
  2 HLA-A*02:01 GLEALMPLAV
  3 HLA-A*02:01 LEALMPLAVI
  4 HLA-A*02:01 EALMPLAVIV
  5 HLA-A*02:01 ALMPLAVIVA
  1 HLA-B*35:01 VTGYKVQYTS
  2 HLA-B*35:01 TGYKVQYTSL
  3 HLA-B*35:01 GYKVQYTSLT
  4 HLA-B*35:01 YKVQYTSLTG
  5 HLA-B*35:01 KVQYTSLTGL
  1 HLA-B*35:01 SHDLGIILQK
  2 HLA-B*35:01 HDLGIILQKI
  3 HLA-B*35:01 DLGIILQKIR
  4 HLA-B*35:01 LGIILQKIRD
  5 HLA-B*35:01 GIILQKIRDM
  6 HLA-B*35:01 IILQKIRDMP
  7 HLA-B*35:01 ILQKIRDMPY
  8 HLA-B*35:01 LQKIRDMPYM
  1 HLA-B*35:01 MGLEALMPLA
  2 HLA-B*35:01 GLEALMPLAV
  3 HLA-B*35:01 LEALMPLAVI
  4 HLA-B*35:01 EALMPLAVIV
  5 HLA-B*35:01 ALMPLAVIVA
```

Now, one can notice that:

1. The `df$Peptide` is essentially the same for each iteration of the `df$Pos` column (it differs by a single aa, because the reading frame is going forward). And **every time the `df$Pos` restarts, it indicates a new Peptide**.
2. Also, notice that half of the data frame is comprised by **HLA-A*02:01** on `df$MHC` column, and the other half by **HLA-B*35:01**. Apart from that, the **peptides are exactly the same for each group, and so should be their names**.

That being said, the second object, `names`, contains defined names for each peptide, as follows:

```
>names
"COL7A1_Pro268Ser"  "COL7A1_Arg1120Lys" "CYP2D6_Val7Met"
```

##### My question is:

How can I combine these 2 objects, so the final data frame looks like this:

```
>df
Pos         MHC    Peptide              Name
  1 HLA-A*02:01 VTGYKVQYTS  COL7A1_Pro268Ser
  2 HLA-A*02:01 TGYKVQYTSL  COL7A1_Pro268Ser
  3 HLA-A*02:01 GYKVQYTSLT  COL7A1_Pro268Ser
  4 HLA-A*02:01 YKVQYTSLTG  COL7A1_Pro268Ser
  5 HLA-A*02:01 KVQYTSLTGL  COL7A1_Pro268Ser
  1 HLA-A*02:01 SHDLGIILQK COL7A1_Arg1120Lys
  2 HLA-A*02:01 HDLGIILQKI COL7A1_Arg1120Lys
  3 HLA-A*02:01 DLGIILQKIR COL7A1_Arg1120Lys
  4 HLA-A*02:01 LGIILQKIRD COL7A1_Arg1120Lys
  5 HLA-A*02:01 GIILQKIRDM COL7A1_Arg1120Lys
  6 HLA-A*02:01 IILQKIRDMP COL7A1_Arg1120Lys
  7 HLA-A*02:01 ILQKIRDMPY COL7A1_Arg1120Lys
  8 HLA-A*02:01 LQKIRDMPYM COL7A1_Arg1120Lys
  1 HLA-A*02:01 MGLEALMPLA    CYP2D6_Val7Met
  2 HLA-A*02:01 GLEALMPLAV    CYP2D6_Val7Met
  3 HLA-A*02:01 LEALMPLAVI    CYP2D6_Val7Met
  4 HLA-A*02:01 EALMPLAVIV    CYP2D6_Val7Met
  5 HLA-A*02:01 ALMPLAVIVA    CYP2D6_Val7Met
  1 HLA-B*35:01 VTGYKVQYTS  COL7A1_Pro268Ser
  2 HLA-B*35:01 TGYKVQYTSL  COL7A1_Pro268Ser
  3 HLA-B*35:01 GYKVQYTSLT  COL7A1_Pro268Ser
  4 HLA-B*35:01 YKVQYTSLTG  COL7A1_Pro268Ser
  5 HLA-B*35:01 KVQYTSLTGL  COL7A1_Pro268Ser
  1 HLA-B*35:01 SHDLGIILQK COL7A1_Arg1120Lys
  2 HLA-B*35:01 HDLGIILQKI COL7A1_Arg1120Lys
  3 HLA-B*35:01 DLGIILQKIR COL7A1_Arg1120Lys
  4 HLA-B*35:01 LGIILQKIRD COL7A1_Arg1120Lys
  5 HLA-B*35:01 GIILQKIRDM COL7A1_Arg1120Lys
  6 HLA-B*35:01 IILQKIRDMP COL7A1_Arg1120Lys
  7 HLA-B*35:01 ILQKIRDMPY COL7A1_Arg1120Lys
  8 HLA-B*35:01 LQKIRDMPYM COL7A1_Arg1120Lys
  1 HLA-B*35:01 MGLEALMPLA    CYP2D6_Val7Met
  2 HLA-B*35:01 GLEALMPLAV    CYP2D6_Val7Met
  3 HLA-B*35:01 LEALMPLAVI    CYP2D6_Val7Met
  4 HLA-B*35:01 EALMPLAVIV    CYP2D6_Val7Met
  5 HLA-B*35:01 ALMPLAVIVA    CYP2D6_Val7Met
```

Please note that I have already searched in different sources, including here. Hence, I am posting this question because I could not find anything similar elsewhere. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Example data:

```
df <- structure(list(Pos = c("1","2","3","4","5","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","1","2","3","4","5","1","2","3","4","5","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","1","2","3","4","5"), MHC = c("HLA-A*02:01","HLA-A*02:01","HLA-A*02:01","HLA-A*02:01","HLA-A*02:01","HLA-A*02:01","HLA-A*02:01","HLA-A*02:01","HLA-A*02:01","HLA-A*02:01","HLA-A*02:01","HLA-A*02:01","HLA-A*02:01","HLA-A*02:01","HLA-A*02:01","HLA-A*02:01","HLA-A*02:01","HLA-A*02:01","HLA-B*35:01","HLA-B*35:01","HLA-B*35:01","HLA-B*35:01","HLA-B*35:01","HLA-B*35:01","HLA-B*35:01","HLA-B*35:01","HLA-B*35:01","HLA-B*35:01","HLA-B*35:01","HLA-B*35:01","HLA-B*35:01","HLA-B*35:01","HLA-B*35:01","HLA-B*35:01","HLA-B*35:01","HLA-B*35:01"), Peptide = c("VTGYKVQYTS","TGYKVQYTSL","GYKVQYTSLT","YKVQYTSLTG","KVQYTSLTGL","SHDLGIILQK",
"HDLGIILQKI","DLGIILQKIR","LGIILQKIRD","GIILQKIRDM","IILQKIRDMP","ILQKIRDMPY","LQKIRDMPYM","MGLEALMPLA","GLEALMPLAV","LEALMPLAVI","EALMPLAVIV","ALMPLAVIVA","VTGYKVQYTS","TGYKVQYTSL","GYKVQYTSLT","YKVQYTSLTG","KVQYTSLTGL","SHDLGIILQK","HDLGIILQKI","DLGIILQKIR","LGIILQKIRD","GIILQKIRDM","IILQKIRDMP","ILQKIRDMPY","LQKIRDMPYM","MGLEALMPLA","GLEALMPLAV","LEALMPLAVI","EALMPLAVIV","ALMPLAVIVA")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(1L,2L,3L,4L,5L,6L,
7L,8L,9L,10L,11L,12L,13L,14L,15L,16L,17L,18L,19L,20L,21L,22L,23L,24L,25L,26L,27L,28L,
29L,30L,31L,32L,33L,34L,35L,36L))

names <- c("COL7A1_Pro268Ser", "COL7A1_Arg1120Lys", "CYP2D6_Val7Met")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```r
# compute the lengths of individual peptides
peptide.len <- diff(c(which(df$Pos == 1), nrow(df)+1))
# repeat the names over the number of peptides
names.rep <- rep(names, length.out=length(peptide.len))
# repeat each name according to peptide lengths
df$Name <- rep(names.rep, peptide.len)
```